# Reset location settings in chrome for android via remote debugging (chrome inspect devices)

Tags: remote-debugging, chrome-for-android

I am looking for an easier way to reset setting for accessing location for Chrome for Android via remote debugging i.e. I want to do it from Chrome desktop application.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Easier than (how do you do it currently)?

Comment: In chrome android app's setting, option for allowing or blocking location access. Clicking on the specific url and reset it.